# Tomcat-7.0.27 how to sort by last modified in listing directory files

Tags: file, sorting, servlets, directory, tomcat7

I use the listing files on tomcat-7.0.27. However, by default the files are sorted by name, and I would do it after the date of modification. 
Can someone write me how to do it step by step?

Comment: Which operation system do you use?

Comment: So normally I would like to deploy to central environment - Linux, Red Hat

Comment: So actually this is a linux Red Hat question right? Because it is about how to list files according to last modification time.

Comment: No, the point is that publish daily the latest version of the mobile application .apk to a directory on the server in question on tomcat. Directory listing does not include sorting by date modified. I would like to change.
Do you know any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the file by using the following parameters.

Suppose you have your files in **http://localhost:8080/doc/.**
You can add following parameters for e.g **http://localhost:8080/doc/?C=N;O=D**. This will sort the by file Name in descending order. The details of different parameters are mentioned below.

```
***C column (N name, M last modified, S size, D description - absent in Tomcat)
O order (A ascending, D descending)***
```